# Jquery Mobile - Radio group change

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am sure I am missing something very obvious, as I new to Jquery. I am using Jquery Mobile with the following markup:

```
<div>
    <input data-theme="c" type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" />
    <label for="radio-choice-1">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input data-theme="c" type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-2">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input data-theme="c" type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-3">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

and I am trying to perform an action when the value changes.

So I have:

```
$(":input[@name='radio-choice-1']").change(function() {
        alert('clicked');
});
```

Now the first time I select an option, the event doesn't fire.  It does fire when I subsequently change it (i.e. the 2nd, 3rd etc. time) but not the first.  I assume it is because it not being 'changed' per se, just given a value.  I tried to changing it to click but then it never fires.

What am I missing here?  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you just pre-select one of the options?

Comment: Obviously I could, and that would work, but that is not I am aiming for.

Comment: are you getting any errors ? if you open your mobile page in a web browser  ?

Comment: No errors. Have tried in Firefox w/ Firebug and no errors reported.  Only tried it on desktop so far, not on mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will help

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(":input[@name='radio-choice-1']").live('change mousedown',function(event) { 
        alert('clicked'); 
}); 

});
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/XVuAs/1/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried that and I get the same thing (i.e. first change gets no response, all subsequent ones do)  What browser were you using?  I am in Safari 5.0.2.

Comment: @Nick Hartley i have added the jsfiddle code.. Can you check that

Comment: Yes that works fine.  Must therefore be a jquery mobile issue.  Bear with me I will get a version online.

Comment: @Nick Hartley I have added jquery.mobile library, can you check it again

Comment: See the link [link](http://www.hartleysonline.co.uk/test/jqm03.html) this has the markup above with your suggested jquery code.

Comment: Thanks Abdul. That still works, but it does not look anything like jquery mobile, which is automatically styled.  I am not familiar with jsfiddle so am not sure whether it is applying the jquery mobile stuff correctly.  Have you seen the link I sent?

Comment: @Nick Hartley found your problem. Add click or mousedown along with change inside live('change mousedown',function(event){ });. That should fix

Comment: Thanks Abdul.  I was using alpha 3 release, when I switched to alpha 4 then it all starting working, using your method above.

Comment: This adds to much overhead just for a change event, see my working example with simple syntax

Comment: @Nick Hartley you can remove the live. Use it only if its a ajax loaded content

Answer (score 13):

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wWFGf/2/

Alternate HTML Syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/wWFGf/3/

```
$("[name=radio-choice-1]").change(function() {
    alert('Selected: '+$('input[name=radio-choice-1]:checked').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was referencing alpha 3 release, which was probably the source of all my problems.  It is working now.

Comment: np. As a tip you want to keep your code base a small as possible as load times on a mobile device will be slower as well as memory resources. Also added alternate syntax

Comment: Nick, thanks for mentioning alpha 3.  Dreamweaver CS5.5 uses alpha 3, so I went to the jQuery mobile site and found the latest cdn release.  That fixed it, like you said.

Comment: I'd use ````this```` inside change callback instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change( function() {
        alert('clicked');
});
```

Above code, tested and working fine for me...

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It is not happening for me.  I tried both Firefox and Safari, and I get the same issue.  The first click does not fire the event, subsequent clicks do.

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically load the page you might need to do something like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').live('changed' function() {
alert('clicked live');  
});
```